# How to find the delta of a graph with a limit that approaches infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

I thought that in order to find $\delta$, given $\epsilon$, you would need to first subtract epsilon from the limit. How would you do that if the limit is infinity?

The exact problem is $(2x+4)^{-1}$ where $x \to -2$,  taking fixed $\epsilon = .05$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a finite limit you add  $\pm \epsilon$, not $\pm \delta$ to the limit.  If you claim $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)=7$, you are asked to prove that whatever $\epsilon \gt 0$ I give you, you can find a $\delta$ such that if $x$ is within $\delta$ of $1$, it produces an $f(x)$ that is within $\pm \epsilon$ of $7$

For a limit of $\infty$, the interval around $f(x)$ is something like $(M,\infty)$.  Instead of being given a small $\epsilon$ around the limit, you are given a large $M$ and you have to show how close to $-2$ you need $x$ to be so $|f(x)| \gt M$

Added:  say we are trying to show $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac 1{(x-1)^2} = +\infty$  Instead of the small $\epsilon$ for a finite limit, I give you a large $M$, say one million.  You have to find a $\delta$ so that for any $x \in (1-\delta,1+\delta)$, we have $\frac 1{(x-1)^2} \gt 10^6$.  Can you see that $\delta=0.001$ will work?

Comment: I am still having a lot of trouble figuring this out. I know I can't ask you to do a problem for me, but can you walk me through a similar problem?

Comment: @AntonYershov:  please see if the update helps.

Comment: Hey this actually helps a lot! Thank you so much :)